# Munit4 throws "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1679456e'"

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft, munit

I try to mock a variable in my munit test;

```
 <munit:behavior >
            <set-payload value='xxxxx' doc:name="Set Payload" doc:id="597412dc-64c7-45e0-87c5-2e8ce3dd967e" mimeType="application/json"/>


     <munit-tools:mock-when doc:name="Mock when" doc:id="fe3ee162-0a52-4b4d-a5bf-127b42b7f6b6" processor="set-variable">
                        <munit-tools:with-attributes >
                            <munit-tools:with-attribute whereValue="ClientId" attributeName="doc:name" />
                            <munit-tools:with-attribute whereValue="clientid" attributeName="variableName" />
                        </munit-tools:with-attributes>
                        <munit-tools:then-return >
                            <munit-tools:variables >
                                <munit-tools:variable key="clientid" value="ss" />
                            </munit-tools:variables>
                        </munit-tools:then-return>
                    </munit-tools:mock-when>
    </munit:behavior>
    <munit:execution >
                <flow-ref doc:name="Flow-ref to post:\raml-main" doc:id="de9bf3d4-cd3f-42e1-89cf-621c3852634e" name="raml-main"/>
            </munit:execution>
            <munit:validation >
                <munit-tools:assert-that doc:name="Assert that" doc:id="292449c4-51e6-4135-afba-c56016b5ef7d" is="#[MunitTools::equalTo(200)]" expression="#[vars.httpStatus]" message="Different status code"/>
            </munit:validation>
```

But when i run the test;
I get;

```
caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1679456e': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.mule.runtime.core.api.config.ConfigurationException: Element 'ss' is not defined in the Mule Registry
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:185) ~[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:137) ~[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]

...........

Caused by: org.mule.runtime.core.api.config.ConfigurationException: Element 'ss' is not defined in the Mule Registry
```

Why is that? I have selected a flow to test.My tests have test properties file, which is working.
I have defined like;

Why I could not mock a variable?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran across your question.  I have been working on the same problem.  I beleive if you use value="#["ss"]" it will work.  I was trying to put 200 in a variable called httpStatus and this seemed to work for me.

```
                <munit-tools:variables >
                    <munit-tools:variable key="httpStatus" value="#[200]" />
                </munit-tools:variables>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me. I'm using mule 4.3 and munit2.

```
<munit-tools:variables >
  <munit-tools:variable key="clientid" value='#["ss"]' />
</munit-tools:variables>
```